# Consider the set of complex matrices of eigenvalue $4$. Which of the following statements are true?

Tags: linear-algebra

Denote by $\mathfrak{U}$ the set of all $n × n$ complex matrices $A$ ($n \geq 2$ a natural number) having the property that $4$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$.
Consider the following four statements.

$\bullet \ (A − 4I)^n = 0$,

$\bullet \ A^n = 4^nI$,

$\bullet \ (A^2 − 5A + 4I)^n = 0$,

$\bullet \ A^n = 4nI$.

Which of the above statements are true for all $A \in \mathfrak{U}$?

Here, there exist a $v\in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $Av=4v$, so $(A-4I)(v)=0$. Then $A^n(v)=4^nv$, so the second statement is true at least for $v$. But, we are not given that $A$ is diagonalizable, so can't say anything for all vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$. So, how to approach this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: In all of the above you can assume that $A$ has a Jordan Normal form. Also, note that $A-4I$ is nilpotent. This fact answers the 1st & 3rd. Taking the simplest $2 \times 2$ non diagonal Jordan form will answer the 2nd & 4th.

Comment: @copper.hat So, assuming $A$ has a Jordan normal form $J$ which implies all the diagonal entries of the $J$ is $4$ which implies all the diagonal entries of $J-4I$ is zero. That means $J-4I$ is nilpotent as all the elements of the lower triangle of the matrix including the diagonal is $0$. So, $A-4I$ is nilpotent. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. All eigenvalues of $A-4I$ are zero, hence $(A-4I)^n = 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, that is the easier way to put it. The second and fourth point is false. I found some counterexamples for $2x2$ matrices. Now, I think the third one is true because by considering the Jordan canonical form I find the diagonal entries of $A^2-5A+4I$ is zero. So, that has to be nilpotent. Am I right?

Comment: The third statement is true. Factor $x^2-5x+4$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you very much for your help.